# Problems with returned function values in differents periods and chart timeframes

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql

I need to do somthing like this

```
if ( iAO( Symbol(),PERIOD_M1, 0) <= iAO( Symbol(), PERIOD_M5, 0) )

{

....

}
```

But  iAO( Symbol(), PERIOD_M5, 0)  does not work when  my chart timeframe is M1 (It return 0 always).

Is it possible to obtain the  real returned value of this function in M1?

---

### **UPDATE**

I found out that the problem is something related with the bars number at the different time frames. something like this:

```
int BM1 = iBars(NULL,PERIOD_M1);
```

where

```
int BM5 = BM1/5;
```

or

```
int BM5 = iBars(NULL,PERIOD_BM5);
```

So, if i do this it does works if i'm in timeframe M1.

```
int i, n=0, Counted_bars;   

Counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();  

i=Bars-Counted_bars-1;



   while(i>=0)                     

   { 

        if (  iAO( Symbol(),PERIOD_M1, i) <= iAO( Symbol(), PERIOD_M5, i/5)  )

        {

...

        }

i--;

}
```

But it only works when i'm programing a indicator. It does not works in a Expert Advisor. ¿Any idea?

Comment: mql4 or mql5? it will work in mql4, for mql5 you need to have handle, copy elements into arrays etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm writing it in MQL4. I found out that the problem is something related with the bars number at the different time frames. something like this:  **int BM1 = iBars(NULL,PERIOD_M1)**  where  **BM5 = BM1/5**
But it only works when i'm programing a indicator. It does no works in a Expert Advisor. ¿Any idea?

Comment: 0 is still the current bar. if you need `i`-th bar, you may need to convert time and bars. `iBarShift` gives the index from time

Comment: It does works!! Thank you so much!!